# Migrate from MediaQuery.fromWindow to MediaQuery.fromView

Tags: flutter

How do I migrate from `MediaQuery.fromWindow` to `MediaQuery.fromView`?

The deprecation message is:

> info: 'fromWindow' is deprecated and shouldn't be used. Use MediaQuery.fromView instead. This constructor was deprecated in preparation for the upcoming multi-window support. This feature was deprecated after v3.7.0-32.0.pre. (deprecated_member_use at [flame_studio] lib/src/widgets/left_panel.dart:15)

The `fromView` method is taking a `FlutterView` instance, can I get that from the context, or how can I get that?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

#### Without context

In case you don't have a context use the below code:

```dart
/// Without context
/// views can be [single, first, last, firstOrNull]
final MediaQueryData data = MediaQueryData.fromView(WidgetsBinding.instance.platformDispatcher.views.single);

return data.size.shortestSide < 600 ? "M" : "T";
```

#### With context

```dart
/// With Context

/// Basically - View.of(context) === WidgetsBinding.instance.window

/// Examples:
/// final double dpr = View.of(context).devicePixelRatio;
/// final Locale locale = View.of(context).platformDispatcher.locale;

MediaQuery.fromView(
  view: View.of(context),
  child: ...
)
```

For more details checkout flutter docs [The window singleton is deprecated](https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/window-singleton)

Comment: This is the best answer. I have no use for View.of() because i need the size property.

Comment: Is it safe to use `.single` method? 
What if there are multiple `views`,(more than one element) then `.single` will throw a StateError

Answer (score 5):

The solution was much simpler than I expected, simply get the `FlutterView` with `View.of(context)`:

```dart
MediaQuery.fromView(
  view: View.of(context),
  child: ...
)
```

Comment: But this solution needs a context.

Comment: It does indeed, otherwise it wouldn't be possible for it to know which window it is for.

Answer (score 1):

If someone need this without context:

> **package:flutter/src/foundation/binding.dart**
> SingletonFlutterWindow get window
>
> **Containing class: BindingBase**
>
> Deprecated. Will be removed in a future version of Flutter. This property has been deprecated to prepare for Flutter's upcoming support for multiple views and multiple windows. It represents the main view for applications where there is only one view, such as applications designed for single-display mobile devices. If the embedder supports multiple views, it points to the first view created which is assumed to be the main view. It throws if no view has been created yet or if the first view has been removed again.
>
> The following options exists to migrate code that relies on accessing this deprecated property: If a BuildContext is available, consider looking up the current FlutterView associated with that context via View.of. It gives access to the same functionality as this deprecated property. However, the platform-specific functionality has moved to the PlatformDispatcher, which may be accessed from the view returned by View.of via FlutterView.platformDispatcher. Using View.of with a BuildContext is the preferred option to migrate away from this deprecated window property.
>
> If no context is available to look up a FlutterView, the platformDispatcher exposed by this binding can be used directly for platform-specific functionality. It also maintains a list of all available FlutterViews in PlatformDispatcher.views to access view-specific functionality without a context.
>
> See also:
>
> - View.of to access view-specific functionality on the FlutterView associated with the provided BuildContext.
> - FlutterView.platformDispatcher to access platform-specific functionality from a given FlutterView.
> - platformDispatcher on this binding to access the PlatformDispatcher, which provides platform-specific functionality.

https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/window-singleton