# What to use instead of MediaQueryData mediaQueryData = MediaQueryData.fromWindow(ui.window);?

Tags: flutter, dart, mediaquery

I am relatively new to flutter, and this is what I was using in my project to get the device's metrics:`MediaQueryData mediaQueryData = MediaQueryData.fromWindow(ui.window);`. However, in VSCode, I keep getting a message saying this has been been deprecated and I cannot quite figure out what to do instead.

I tried reading the flutter documentation, but it is not completely clear what to do, at least to me.

Comment: Instead of using `MediaQuery.fromWindow(ui.window)`, you should use `MediaQueryData.fromView(ui.window)` instead.

For more information on this topic, you can check out the following link on StackOverflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76226720/migrate-from-mediaquery-fromwindow-to-mediaquery-fromview.

Comment: @Sami hi thanks, i tried that, but it says window is deprecated and i have to use view? read the linked question but still unclear

Comment: You should use "fromView" since "fromWindow" is deprecated.

Answer (score -1):

to get the device metrics use :

```
MediaQuery.of(context).size.height
MediaQuery.of(context).size.width
```

Comment: Use `MediaQuery.sizeOf(context)` instead. It only rebuilds when the size changes, avoiding unnecessary rebuilds caused by changes in other MediaQuery properties.